# Preventing div from being wrapped on smaller screen html css

Tags: html, css

I have this html:

```
<b><li>DATA</li></b>
    <form>
        <ol type="a">
            <div class="form-group row my-1">
                <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label nowrap"><li>Name</li></label>
                <div class="nowrap">
                    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext nowrap" id="staticEmail" value="{{ $kredit->debitur->name or '-' }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row my-1">
                <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"><li>Alamat</li></label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" value="{{ $kredit->debitur->alamat or '-' }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row my-1">
                <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"><li>Tempat / Tgl Lahir</li></label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" value="{{ $kredit->debitur->tempat_lahir or '-' }} / {{ $kredit->debitur->tanggal_lahir or '-' }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </ol>
    </form>
```

The output is something like:

```
a. Name                 FooBar
b. Alamat               Some Text
c. Tempat/Tanggal Lahir Some Other Text / somedate
```

However when I resize the screen it goes like this:

```
a. Name                 
   FooBar
b. Alamat               
   Some Text
c. Tempat/Tanggal Lahir
   Some Other Text / somedate
```

Which I don't want. I want to force it to stay inline and use horizontal scroll bar instead.

I have already tried `white-space: nowrap;` and `display: inline-block;` but for my case the html is already made by someone else (there are a lot more) and I can't easily implement them. I want to avoid rewriting if possible.

edit:
I ended up using this

```
    .nowrap {
        flex: 1;
        width: 300px;
        float: left;
    }

    .container {
        display: flex;
    }
```

Not perfect but good enough for my case.

Comment: instead of using the inline-block try flex properties.

Comment: Add your css too

Comment: are you using bootstrap 3 or bootstrap 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Flex on the direct parent container.
Here is the code.

```css
div.row{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
}
.row > label, .row > div{
  min-width: 150px;
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<form>
        <ol type="a">
            <div class="form-group row my-1">
                <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label nowrap"><li>Name</li></label>
                <div class="nowrap">
                    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext nowrap" id="staticEmail" value="{{ $kredit->debitur->name or '-' }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row my-1">
                <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"><li>Alamat</li></label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" value="{{ $kredit->debitur->alamat or '-' }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row my-1">
                <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"><li>Tempat / Tgl Lahir</li></label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" value="{{ $kredit->debitur->tempat_lahir or '-' }} / {{ $kredit->debitur->tanggal_lahir or '-' }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </ol>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

very easy and simple way with media query define your own screen width instead of 767px

`@media(max-width:767px) {
    .nowrap {display:block;}

}`